# Why can I use type assertions with literals such as `false`?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I can [successfully compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDKAnArgUxgQwjAMxwBsJMBuAWACgg) following code:

```
const x = true as false;
```

So I have a constant `x` with value `true` and type `false`. I expected that such direct assertions should be invalid, but surprisingly it is valid. For example, for the [similar code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDADDAhhGAzdAbCAUwG4BYAKCA)

```
const x = 0 as false;
```

there is a compilation error

> Conversion of type 'number' to type 'false' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

I expected a similar error to occur with `true` and `false`.

Why there is no error and is there a way (like some set of compiler options) to fix it?

Comment: It's not a *cast*, it's a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). You're telling the compiler you know better.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I know, but usually ts asks to add additional cast to `unknown` or `any` in such cases, but not here by some reason.

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14156; true and false are the same primitive type

Comment: @jonrsharpe, actually I don't understand why they closed this issue. The [story](http://www.johnfn.com/ts-best-line.html) is interesting, but: 1. It's not the common case, and you can always use `false as any as true` for that. 2. There is much better solution [`ReturnType<typeof f>`](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet).

Comment: I didn't write it. If you want to debate the language, do so with the maintainers, but you asked why and that's why. In the meantime, just don't write illogical type assertions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I'm actually doing this https://codesandbox.io/s/p2y18 (seems like codesandbox has some mistakes in showing types, copy code to ts playground) and there are many cases when I have to write smth like `true as WithOptPayload<true, { v: string }>,` and in case of changing true to false I need to change it in 2 places. May ask in a separate question if there is a solution.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, asked a question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842858/4928642.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because typescript expands the types themselves. true and false do overlap, they are both boolean types.
0 and false don't overlap, one is a number, the other a boolean.

Comment: No chances to fix?

Comment: Probably not, it's strange, but the alternative would force a double cast.

Comment: I think, it's a very rare case when you actually want to do `true as false`, and that's ok to use double cast in that cases, isn't it?

Comment: It's a rare case yes, except when it's not. The rules serves more purposes than just casting a primitive to another.

Comment: Besides, there isn't much of a reason to do it. the only time you could guarantee what you assert is when the declaration is hardcoded.

Comment: I'm actually doing this https://codesandbox.io/s/p2y18 (seems like codesandbox has some mistakes in showing types, copy code to ts playground) and there are many cases when I have to write smth like `true as WithOptPayload<true, { v: string }>,` and in case of changing true to false I need to change it in 2 places. May ask in a separate question if there is a solution.

Comment: Asked a question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62842858/4928642.