# Pass generic type argument through the literal object with different field names per each field if number of fields values is limited by 4

Tags: typescript, generics, casting

## What am I doing?

I want to make mapping of an object field-by-field to objects of some generic type. I have 4 runtime cases (with runtime check and throwing exception if not matches) that I've used as a properties of original object:

- `false` transforms to `Smth<unknown> | undefined`
- `true` transforms to `Smth<unknown>`
- `[]` transforms to `Smth<unknown>` with 0 or more elements
- `[true]` transforms to `Smth<unknown>` with 1 or more elements

Actually that's not very difficult, but I'm not very happy to have `unknown` in generic everywhere. In some cases I want to specify what `payload` exactly this `Smth` should have (compile-time assertion only, no any runtime checks planned). For this purpose I've found solution with casting the four values to types having additional optional field:

```
type WithOptPayload<T, P> =  T & { payload?: P }
getColDefsByKinds({ b: false as WithOptPayload<false, { u: 99 }> })
```

### And that really [works fine (playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgeTMACgQxAGwPaYAmAPACoA0U6AfFALxRSlQBkUA3lGNvkQPwAuKlAC+AWABQkgMZ4AdgGdgUAB70oAcwjAAwnhwARCADMFAIRABpOHMIKAFO0mNGmIccw4FEcs5cAjd09vKEwFWAQUNCxcAhIPLx8OKABXIQBOdNFqXwkXKGkhYAAnFJ8-RkIi0ugwiKRUDB444hKyyk4ANyElYpsNbNz8iCEAbQBdIZdjMfHQ8PgG6OaiYgmOqAB3ITkUgFt-CGLBis0xtohJ08Rzmrm6xaim2NXRi8nQuRAcyREASgA3JJJKBIFAAJLGACiKmAEFsCmIABlKAAlSgATUoADl1HIIJ0jrQGEioBBYfC7FBUVA+FAMVAhNjgRIbHDih5pNAAMp7JDEdDqFJyADWcjwmzktCceRcKh6JX6p24LyqVF+LNB0GstnUCRCAB8oBcoEbihAiPIcCAoBNTVBzZa5Nbbe8QeBoABVOTcaQi4gAMTJFIRUB1hDREAUxIh0JDdkDlAukYUlEhMLhCMTUH1SVRUftwsIJhsEAj1KjE2o1BZxmF0mAcHkmm0ekMJnMVhsCeY5MzVM4oxFEBACr6cg04yE4ey9kQEqEpD+QkHIu7UBsUGHIDwxiYU6g3t9-tIQ+7H15-NPa9scz7lPCnBVvEIgg3cmMR2EIlpwiEwrFCUpVoH8ZXyc1gBSYo5CgXYcBwABCDUJCAA):

[image: Screenshot of inferred type]

```
type WithOptPayload<T, P> =  T & { payload?: P }

const x = getColDefsByKinds({
    a: false,
    b: false as WithOptPayload<false, { u: 99 }>,
    c: true,
    d: true as WithOptPayload<true, { v: string }>,
    e: [],
    f: [] as WithOptPayload<[], { w: number }>,
    g: [true],
    h: [true] as WithOptPayload<[true], any>,
});

type IfExtends<L, R, Y, N = never> = L extends R ? Y : N

interface Smth<P = unknown> {
    x: string
    payload: P
}

type Kind = false | true | readonly [] | readonly [true]
type Unpack<F extends Kind, Res> = IfExtends<F, true, Res, IfExtends<F, false, Res | undefined, Res[]>>

function getColDefsByKinds<T extends { [key: string]: Kind }>(how: T): { [kind in keyof T]: Unpack<T[kind], Smth<T[kind] extends { payload?: infer P } ? P : unknown>> } {
    return null!
}
```

And a bit [more complicated version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgeTMACgQxAGwPaYAmAPACoA0U6AfFALxSlQQAewEAdoQM5QCuXCADM4HCISgB+RlABkUAN5Qw2fEUkAuKlAC+UAD79BIsRK1N5SlbgKFN2nQFgAUC4DGeDt2BQW9KADmEMAAwng4ACLC3ABCIADSojwAFAouUBlQmFpCmDjcEOTpmQBGOXkFWbzwSKgYqrbEufmFivxaAJwdutRFzplQblrAAE58hcUZhMNj0JjVCChoWDZExKPjlEoAblreI6IBPX0DEFoA2gC6J5lCF5dVsIt1K2okV1tQAO5aHHwAtiUICNjpNAhcNhBrmDEBDZg95k9assGmtzpDrlkOCBei4dABKFzuTzeKAgfxBULhKJCWIJJLcVJg7JQZqVRFs6CGASEYSicQ3DJlVkVOYLZH1VYkTkGIy8kwCtp8TrdHS4-qZIZQSGPHXc4z8wiCqDTbWzR41JaSt7rWafXZQfaHUEajJnKBXR6e-Xyw3Gu4ehHiq2vRreuV80yfH5QP6A4EuglE5weLw+ABeFOCYUi0TiiS4jLSrqyM3GjxKeHCEEwHGNwp1iMtL1RJEr1drlCdHAC6oGWsbvHbOBrdbBpsHSJDreIw9HXdGhz7mXdPMjArBATh42hJdhHoxFueKKlxHR8MotZxfSTrmcoEgUAAkkIAKJsTg8YgAGUoACVKAATUoAA5fwxG2YFaAYb9mA-QsoD-KQoEAqAtBA5NRHYEZcjcaAAGV-iQYh0H8AQAGsODwL4OFoYsBhYPZFx7MFrDeLR0DxZMH2gAsJAYGVDD1CMFQkQwRhrQhPBwclwwkohpNkjEXB4qAAFUOBUNxyOIAAxOD2AQvj-wgbhoKgd83BwPheWIF930Mr9dMoNdRJcg1TFoQx7PgpzKEhEyzNlHzHO4PTKE5QLZVcw0vOfN9fLC5yoDnWtoo8xUIOBQKrl6WMIEgkZqGTIQBDcYA4E8QJs2pPN6ULMgDM-XglHOciIBAJiDh7S4tD4npkkQajzHxLRWvIpIoFEKB2pAPAhEYXr1M0zBtLINqkkxQjiMs6zbNIDauExGLPKahCrFbexRCEBNSL0aRSK0CiqJo6haD0ejMgk4A+BGDhYz4HAcAAQi45wgA) with

```
type WithOptPayload<T, P> = T extends undefined ? T & { payload?: P } | undefined : T & { payload?: P }

type Kind = false | true | undefined | readonly [] | readonly [true]
type Unpack<F extends Kind, Res> = Exclude<IfExtends<F, undefined, undefined> | IfExtends<F, true, Res> | IfExtends<F, false, Res | undefined> | IfExtends<F, boolean | undefined, never, Res[]>, never>

function getColDefsByKinds<T extends { [key: string]: Kind }>(how: T): { [kind in keyof T]: Unpack<T[kind], Smth<Exclude<T[kind], undefined> extends { payload?: infer P } ? P : unknown>> } {
    return null!
}
```

## What's the problem?

As you see, in the line

```
b: false as WithOptPayload<false, { u: 99 }> }
```

I need to use type `false` twice. Not a long word to write, but there is the other issue: typescript considers [`true as false` is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62841917/4928642). So following lines are compiled without errors and lead to mismatch of runtime and compiletime types:

```
x: false as WithOptPayload<true, { u: 99 }>,
y: true as WithOptPayload<false, { u: 99 }>,
z: [true] as WithOptPayload<[], any>,
```

**I need such casts to be an error.**

Or maybe I can use some other way of passing a type to the mapping function. But there is a limitation: all property names should be written only once as they are different from call to call and do not match any interface.